# Alignment issue with dropdown list

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Is there anything I can do about this?

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("MySelectedReport",Model.MyList,new {style="width:220px;"}) %>
```

[alignement issue](http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/8082/capturetqp.png)

P.S. This only happens in IE 9,8. Firefox and Chrome are rendering the dropdown aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you probably have something like this in you css `select { border: 1px solid #ccc }`. If you remove `border` style of `select` element, your dropdown will be rendered correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that might be the cause. But indeed this seems to be an IE specific issue. Thank you!

Comment: If you care about that border you can try [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) - it looks ok in IE.

Answer (score 0):

From what I belive, its an IE only trait Im afraid :(

Another lovely IE problem!

Comment: Yep, it would seem so. If i remove the border it aligns ok on IE. But on FF and Chrome works just fine with or without the border attribute set.